# Why can i not place an order with the python-binance library?

Tags: python, api, byte, encode, binance

Im using the given function from python-binance library to place an order, but im just getting an error in my Terminal. Other functions like `client.get_server_time()` are working, but not the function to place an order.

Order Function:

```
from binance.enums import *
order = client.create_order(
    symbol='BNBBTC',
    side=SIDE_BUY,
    type=ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,
    timeInForce=TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
    quantity=100,
    price='0.00001')
```

```
thats the error im getting:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 82, in <module>
    price='0.00001')
  File "C:\Python_3.7\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 1345, 
in create_order
    return self._post('order', True, data=params)
  File "C:\Python_3.7\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 323, in _post
    return self._request_api('post', path, signed, version, **kwargs)  
  File "C:\Python_3.7\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 265, in _request_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python_3.7\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 243, in _request
    kwargs['data']['signature'] = self._generate_signature(kwargs['data'])
  File "C:\Python_3.7\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 198, in _generate_signature
    m = hmac.new(self.API_SECRET.encode('utf-8'), query_string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: what are the values for your `SIDE_BUY` , `ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT`, `TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC` variables?

Comment: the values are given from the binance.enums import.

Comment: Without knowing the library I would guess the problem is related to the way you set the API secret when creating the "client" object. You probably try to set it as bytes object where a string is expected.

Comment: I replaced the variables with the values. side="BUY", type="LIMIT", timeInForce="GTC" but still the same error output. These are the same values like in config.py